# Discover new IP address by calling MAC address

Tags: networking, dhcp, ip

I have two devices that is located on a remote network:

- A Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 20.04. Let us call it `Alex`.
- Raspberry Pi Pico Wireless running my code only. Let us call it `Bob`.

`Alex` acts as a gateway of sort for `Bob` only.

They both share the same local network, but for the exercise of the day you can assume they are both assigned dynamic ip from a local DHCP server and static ip is **not** an option.

I know the `Alex` can discover that its ip has changed by using `dhcpcd-hooks`.

But the tricky part is how to discover `Bob` has a new ip address and find out what the new ip address is?

It is safe to assume `Bob` cannot change its MAC address, so can `Alex` use that fact to discover the new ip address?

The failback solution is of course doing a `nmap` scanning of the entire subnet and find out which ip address responded with the right MAC address, but that sounds a bit excessive.

Comment: Won't the `ip route` command faithfully display the correct gateway?

Comment: If you know the MAC address you could also do `arp -a | grep [MAC address]`.

Comment: `ip route` does not work because that means we have access to the router. `Alex` only acts as a gateway for `Bob` for one particular service only. `Bob` is basically a thermometer with built-in WiFi capabilities, so it has a very limited understanding on network setup. :-)

Comment: My understanding of `arp` is that the table only shows MAC addresses from known ips, but if the IP has changed on both `Alex` and `Bob`, like for instance DHCP client table was purged, then they would not know how to find each other - unless I use `nmap` of the entire subnet.

Comment: Couldn't you query the DHCP server?

Comment: As far as I can tell there are no standard way of querying a server. The only way I have come up with besides `nmap` is by creating my own UDP based communication protocol and take advantage of the subnet broadcast address. I.e. sending a message to everyone on a specific port saying something like: "calling ab:cd:ef:12:34:56:78:90 - please answer!" ... and then make `Bob` listen for that UDP port.

Comment: I have a `nmap -sn` running every couple of minutes to detect changes.

Comment: That is a bit excessive. I would just use a TCP session with keepalive enabled to discover "something happened". If session dies and cannot be re-established, then fallback to UDP discovery using broadcast address. That way the client can use the source address in the UDP package as basis for the next TCP session which would make server learn the new ip address.